# Django Create New entries corresponding to existing Foreign Key database entries

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, foreign-keys, django-2.0

I have a Table Books which has 100 entries.

```
class Books(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I have another Table Titles which is newly created and has a Foreign Key relation.

```
class Titles(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Books, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ..........
```

Can I automatically create 100 new entries for Titles based on the existing entry for Books?

Or does changing Foreign Key to a different relation help?

Please help me out or point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about creating them automatically, but you can certainly create them quite easily.

Open a django shell with `python manage.py shell` and do something like:

```
from my_app.models import Books, Titles

for book in Books.objects.all():
    new_title = Titles.objects.create(Books=book, ...)
```

P.S. The model naming convention would be 'Book' not 'Books' and 'Title' not 'Titles'.

Comment: Thank You. This is exactly what I was looking for.